# use string in a $_COOKIE[]?

Tags: php, cookies

so is there any way to do it. i want to put a string as the cookie name instead of a definite cookie name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cookie name is always a string. Do you mean if you can substitute it with a variable? Yes, as with any other string.

```
setcookie($someString, ...);
$_COOKIE[$someString];
```

Comment: wow thank you i was leaving a comma into the bracket, that's why it wasn't working